# Byebug gem configuraiton issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails debugging. I am using **Byebug** gem to **debug** controllers.
I have kept the "Byebug" keyword at somepoint in controller and execution is halting, i can see the same at terminal and working on it.

When i do "**next**" it's moving to next line and checking the value and byebug getting the values.
Once it reach at the end of the function and type "next" it's going to action_controller gems code.

I don't want to debug gems code, pointer should come back to pointer or related view. Since then if i do "step", it's taking me a long journey with many gems source code. i don't want that long journey, just it should come back quickly to either controller or viewer or whatever code it follows in the app folder.

To do that do i need set any configuration for byebug or how to avoid to jump into gems source code.

Could someone please enlighten to me

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do what you want, but you can try to implement it yourself: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/47 :)

In the meantime, you need to manually set breakpoints to jump from controller to view and the other way around.